# Ubuntu 18.04 does not boot on battery power

Tags: boot, 18.04, dell

Recently firmware including BIOS were updated on my laptop (Dell Precision 7530) and since then my Ubuntu does not boot on battery.

The problem happens when I enter Grub2 and are about to select boot option. Then after click on Ubuntu it gets stuck at `Loading initial ramdisk...`. It does not matter which kernel I select (5.3, 5.0, 4.15 etc) or whether I go simply after `Ubuntu` or `Advanced Options`. A behavior is the same for recovery mode.

It also does not want to hibernate (or sleep) - the mode that is activated if you click and hold for short while power button. I have a dual boot and Windows 10 loads fine on battery, there is only a problem with Ubuntu. There is no problem while laptop is on power. I can switch off plug and work on battery after system boot.

Any ideas on what the problem can be and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the below solution to my problem today:

Update : The solution is at the below link

https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7540-will-only-boot-Linux-if-charger-is-connected/m-p/7523968#M3185

```
Adding kernel parameters solves the issue. Posting solution:

in /etc/default/grub add dis_ucode_ldr in this way

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr"

then

sudo update-grub
```

Update2: The grub menu is not visible (purple screen) but waiting or pressing enter do the job to boot on ubuntu.